# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - Appium - TestNG Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, import-from-excel

We are seeing the Java heap space exception while running the Appium Android test scripts execution on Windows machine. We have test data sheet reading using Apache POI. Till 11th script suite is running fine, from 12th script onwards seeing Java Heap space exception.

I have increased heap and prem space `enter code here` in system environment variable and TestNG Run Configuration in the Eclipse. Sometimes no issue, sometimes Java heap space exception experienced.

With the below message I am suspecting reading of test data sheet using fileinputstream, based on other forums it takes more memory while loading although test data doesn't have huge data.

Code I have used is:

```
File strExecutionConfigFile = new File(
            strImportedExecutionConfigFilePath);

try {
        strInputExecutionConfigFile = new FileInputStream(
                strExecutionConfigFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        objExecutionConfigWKB = new XSSFWorkbook(
                strInputExecutionConfigFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am seeing XSSF reader format will consume low memory. Can provide code on this.

You can access below link for Java heap space exception

https://app.box.com/s/9t3or72lk44liolz8x22n9s0pk2klrna

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect the heap dump. Add the following VM args:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/some/location
```

This will dump something like the following the next time you get OOME

```
java_pid27643.hprof
```

Then use jvisualvm to load the heapdump. The command in linux is:

```
$ jvisualvm &
```

You will need to load and inspect the dump file and try to figure out what is causing the OOME. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jvisualvm.html)